# A step in proving the graph of a Borel map is Borel

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

In the appendix Takesaki's book on theory of operator algebras, he showed that if $f$ is a Borel map from a metric space $X$ to a metric space $Y$, then the graph of $f$ is a Borel set of $X \times Y$. An important step in this proof is the following:

If $(Z, d)$ is a metric space and $g: Z \to Z\,$ is a Borel map, then $z \mapsto d(z, g(z))$ is a Borel map from $Z$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I can understand the above statement if $Z$ is separable. However, I fail to see how to prove it in the general case when the metric space $Z$ is not separable. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @JonathanHole Could you explain why the pointwise limits of Borel maps remain Borel? I know we can prove this when the target space is $\mathbb{R}$ for which we can use the order structure. However, $Z$ is merely a metric space...

Comment: If $g_n \rightarrow g$ pointwise and $U\subset Z$ is open, we for each natural number $k$ define $U_k:=\{x\in U : B(x;1/k)\subset U\}$. Then $g(z)\in U$ iff there exists a $k'$ such that eventually $\{g_n(z)\}_n$ is contained in $U_{k'}$. Hence $g^{-1}(U)$ is measurable if the $g_n$'s are.

Comment: But the other direction, that any Borel map is contained in the smallest class of functions containing the continuous ones that is closed under pointwise limits, might not be true. I’ll try to think more about it